# Unable to import self-made classes into IntelliJ GUI designer form's corresponding class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am currently unable to use any classes that I have written into the IntelliJ GUI Designer form's corresponding class unless they are within the same package. I already invalidated IntelliJ's caches with no change. Anyone know what's going on here?
[image]

EDIT: Crud. *Anything* within the maingui package cannot view any self-made classes outside of it now.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the source folder to a generic package and back to the source folder fixed it. Don't ask me why. I don't know.